# Age verification with credit card and payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card

I am developing a gaming website in which the user must be aged above 18 in order to make a payment and start a game. And I am looking for a solution to verify the age using the credit card by which the user will be making payment through the website.

Is it possible to verify the card holders age with the help of any recognized payment gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to verify the card holders age with the help of any
>   recognized payment gateway?

I had a credit card when I was 17.  If you need to verify the user is 18 or older for legal reasons you must achieve this another way.  I wish this answer was longer, but at the end of the day, the answer is honestly a single sentence.

Comment: More like a single word, as extremely few banks allow external payment gates to receive personal data about clients.